# Prevent user stops anything when form is submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, magento, submit, form-submit

Is there a way that once a form is submitted can't refresh or stop the page?

What I did was that when you click ESC does nothing but still is the X in the navigation bar where you can stop the page.

So I'm wondering if I can do something to prevent that something happen when the user wants to stop the loading page.

Thank you.

Comment: can't prevent user interacting with their browser functionality

Comment: @charlietfl is correct.  You can't prevent the user from interacting with their browser.

Comment: Seems logic, thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way of preventing the user from interacting with their browser. Issues with the user navigating away or canceling the request before it completes are usually handled by instructional messaging while the request is being processed (i.e. "Please wait while we process your request. Do not press your browser's back button or we might lose your information.").

Comment: Well, I have to ask. Thank you for your answer :)